# MDriven compatible with .net standard library (.net core)

Tags: mdriven

Can I use Mdriven/ECO in a project based on .NET Core?  In other words does it use the .NET Standard Library?  If not, are there any plans to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Handles, Interfaces and LinqExtender is available for .Net Standard 2 (client logic)
The Persistence assembly is not currently available for .Net Standard due to the fact that Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is not available in Core or in Standard.

**Update Sep 2020**
We have fully implemented the WebApi and a new video on how to set up the persistenceMapperWebAPI that resides in MDriven.http.dll is found here
https://youtu.be/mc66E3bZYe8

This means that you may build a peristence server exposing WebApi - and MDrivenServer has been updated to fully support WebApi.

We haven not tried to write the server in core yet - but all client parts communicating over webapi will work.

Comment: Hello,

Any news about wcf replacement? Why I am asking - I found the checkbox in MDriven Designer's Cloud Form with description "WebApi to MDriven Server (Deprecating WCF)"
Thank you!